# Nested KendoGrid with Kendo Tabstrip error

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I have a grid within a grid.  The 2nd grid is shared with a tabstrip inside a panel.  Everything works as expected until i include my Tabstrip code. The error I get in chrome console is this:

```
Uncaught Error: Invalid template:
```

My view code:

```
 @(Html.Kendo().Grid<MVC.Models.Msg>()
    .Name("MsgGrid")    
    .Events(e => e.DataBound("LineItems_Databound"))
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        //.ClientTemplate("#= LineItems_Databound(Status)#")
        columns.Bound(p => p.ID).Width(50).Hidden(true).HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "Refreshpage" });
        columns.Bound(p => p.Company).Title(@"<span  tabindex=5>Company</span>").Width(75);
        columns.Bound(p => p.Type).Title(@"<span  tabindex=5>Type</span>").Width(75);

    })
    .Pageable(pager =>  pager.Messages(Info => Info.Empty("No Results Found")))
    .Filterable()   
    .Sortable()
    .ClientDetailTemplateId("messagetemplate")
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()
            .PageSize(6)
            .Read(read => read.Action("PaginationGrid", "Controller"))            
        )       
      )


<script id="messagetemplate" type="text/kendo-tmpl">
    <div class="col-md-6"> 
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<MVC.Models.MsgDetails>()
          .Name("msgid_#=ID#")
          .Columns(columns =>
              {
                  columns.Bound(e => e.Type).Width("35%").Filterable(filterable => filterable.Extra(false).Operators(ops => ops.ForString(str => str.Clear().Contains("Contains")))).Encoded(false);
                  columns.Bound(e => e.Description).Width("35%").Filterable(filterable => filterable.Extra(false).Operators(ops => ops.ForString(str => str.Clear().Contains("Contains")))).Encoded(false);
                  columns.Bound(e => e.DetailsDate).Width("30%").Format("{0: dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss}").Filterable(filterable => filterable.Extra(false).Operators(ops => ops.ForString(str => str.Clear().Contains("Contains")))).Encoded(false);
              })
          .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "overflow-y: hidden;" })
          .Pageable(pager => pager.Messages(Info => Info.Empty("No Results Found")))
          .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                                        .Ajax()
                                        .PageSize(10)
                                        .Read(read => read.Action("DetailPaginationGrid", "Controller", new { MsgID = "#=ID#" }))
          )
          .Filterable()
          .Pageable()
          .Sortable(sortable => sortable.AllowUnsort(false))
          .ToClientTemplate()
          )
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h2>Messages</h2>
                <hr />
            </div>
            <div class="k-content">
                 @(Html.Kendo().TabStrip()
                      .Name("messageStrip")
                      .Items(tabstrip =>
                          {
                              tabstrip.Add()
                                      .Text("msg1")
                                      .Selected(true)
                                      .Encoded(false)
                                      .ContentHtmlAttributes(new { style = "overflow: auto;" })
                                      .Content(@<text>
                                                <div id="message1" class="panel-body">
                                                    #=message1# 
                                                 </div>
                                            </text>);

                              tabstrip.Add()
                                      .Text("msg2")
                                      .Encoded(false)
                                      .ContentHtmlAttributes(new { style = "overflow: auto;" })
                                      .Content(@<text>
                                                <div id="message2" class="panel-body">
                                                    #=message2# 
                                                 </div>
                                            </text>);
                          })
                 )
                </div>
    </div>

</script>
```

My question is how is this tabstrip making it an invalid template? Where do I need to make changes... thanks

Comment: Is this too complex of a question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need add `.ToClientTemplate()` to tabstrip same as you added it to grid

```
@(Html.Kendo().TabStrip()
...
.ToClientTemplate())
```